# Gutenberg не видит блок, созданный через ACF PRO

Tags: php, wordpress, gutenberg

Создаю блок для Гутена через ACF PRO. Первый раз столкнулся с проблемой, что мои блок не отображается в списке блоков Гутенберга.
Сделано все по инструкции.  Подскажите, где косяк, не могу понять.

Зарегистрировал в fucntion.php

```
add_action('acf/init', 'review_block_init');
function review_block_init() {

    // Check function exists.
    if( function_exists('acf_register_block_type') ) {

        // Register a testimonial block.
        acf_register_block_type(array(
            'name'              => 'review',
            'title'             => __('Review Block'),
            'description'       => __('A custom review block.'),
            'render_template'   => 'acf-blocks/block-review.php',
            'category'          => 'formatting',
        ));
    
    }
}
```

И создал шаблон:

```
<?php

/**
 * Review Block Template.
 *
 * @param   array $block The block settings and attributes.
 * @param   string $content The block inner HTML (empty).
 * @param   bool $is_preview True during AJAX preview.
 * @param   (int|string) $post_id The post ID this block is saved to.
 */


?>

<div class="review">
    test
</div>
```

Сам ACF блок увидел и я заполнил для него поля, а вот вставить его на страницы не могу.

Comment: Возможно проблема в пути? У вас точно в корне темы есть папка "acf-blocks"? Попробуйте использовать абсолютный путь

Comment: @fortavey, папка точно есть, но я попробовал через абсолют и ничего(

Comment: А если использовать 'render_callback' вместо 'render_template'?

Comment: @fortavey, увы. У меня не в рендере проблема, а в том, что я даже выбрать это блок не могу, что-бы поставить на страницу, его просто нету в списке блоков. 
По идеи , когда я его регистрирую он должен уже быть там, но после регистрации ACF видит блок, а Guter - нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если вы все разместили верно и блок не появляется вариантах, значит у вас скорее всего совпали идентификаторы полей, если блок с таким идентификатор существует то ваш блок не будет отображатся в вариантах блоков. вот так должно работать

```
add_action('acf/init', 'review_block_init');
function review_block_init() {

    // Check function exists.
    if( function_exists('acf_register_block_type') ) {

        // Register a testimonial block.
        acf_register_block_type(array(
            'name'              => 'custom_review',
            'title'             => __('Review Block'),
            'description'       => __('A custom review block.'),
            'render_template'   => 'acf-blocks/block-review.php',
            'category'          => 'formatting',
        ));
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я переделал на шорткод, что бы не тратить время, но ваш вариант мне в голову не пришел, хотя он действительно очевидный.
По возможности проверю догадку